# External script debugger in IE9 (32bit) does not open and debugging JS with VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Can't open external script debugger in IE9 (32bit)

Mainmenu: View -> External script debugger -> Open.

Though in 64bit version it works good.

I have VS2010 installed, and trying to debug JS within my ASP.NET MVC web-application.
Unable to do it anyway with my VS.

I know the easiest way to fix it: re-install windows, but is there any other solution to fix it. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
when I click on IE9 32bit "Mainmenu: View -> External script debugger -> Open" NOTHING happens.

Comment: ... what specifically does it do/say?

Comment: when I click on IE9 32bit "Mainmenu: View -> External script debugger -> Open" NOTHING happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed VS11 and now debugging works again in VS2010 too =). MS magic.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working for me by resetting the debugging options. My inspiration was [from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z959x58c%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

These are the steps I took to get it working for me:

1. In IE9, open `Tools > Internet options > Advanced` tab
2. In browsing category, **check** the boxes next to both `disable script debugging` options
3. Hit `OK` and restart IE9
4. Open `Tools > Internet options > Advanced` tab and **clear** the boxes next to both `disable script debugging` options
5. Hit `OK` and restart IE9
6. Now navigate to your web site and select `View > Script Debugger > Open`
7. Select the debugger of choice from the resulting dialog box.